# With jsonb in Postgres (used with Django's JSONField) what does a unique index actually do?

Tags: django, postgresql

```
class JsonHavingModel(models.Model):
  the_field = JSONField(unique=True)
```

This does something like:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX app_jsonhavingmodel_the_field_c1f3c983_uniq ON app_jsonhavingmodel (the_field);
```

But what does that actually mean?  Does it check just keys?  Just values?  Just the literal JSON text?  Does is check the whole object hierarchy?  Is this a stupid question?  What is the meaning of life?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means exactly what you would expect it to mean - that the values in that column have to be unique across that table.

Assuming your column is a jsonb value that means that the structures are compared for equality.

```
SELECT '{"a":3, "b":2}'::jsonb = '{"b":2, "a":3}'::jsonb;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I can't believe I asked the question to begin with when I could have just tried it out.  I was so tired I was a little delirious yesterday :p.